# how to get all entries with a timestamp sooner than last 24hours?

Tags: postgresql, epoch

How to get last 24h entries based on linux timestamp in seconds ?
like 1658754064 for example.

I tried

```
  SELECT * from some_table
  WHERE timestamp::DATE > (CURRENT_DATE - INTERVAL '1 day')
```

but I get  `cannot cast type bigint to date` error.

Comment: Apparently your column named `timestamp` isn't a timstamp, but a `bigint`.

Comment: yes thanks, 'timestamp' is not the right term for psql indeed

Comment: https://blog.sql-workbench.eu/post/epoch-mania/